# Is it possible to "cancel" a dependency-property assignment from an IValueConverter, if there was no change in the property value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, dependency-properties

I have a data-binding set on a dependency property of a class. I also have an IValueConverter to handle the calculation of this value based on other elements. The context of my question is inside the IValueConverter.Convert method.

**#1**
If the calculated return value is equal to the current property value, can I tell the framework not to bother with SetValue since there was no logical change? Or will the framework detect this automatically, and not waste time setting the property internally?

**#2**
If the calculated return value is invalid for this property, can I tell the framework to leave the property at its current value, rather than setting it to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`Binding.DoNothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx).